# "Transferring" SSL certificate to another person

Tags: tls, certificates, webserver, http

Last year, I did a lot of work on a site as a freelancer. We wanted to put the whole thing behind HTTPS, so, for reasons I can't recall but probably expediency-related, I purchased a cert for it under my personal account at a service that sells certificates. At the end of the year, I stopped working for the client to have more personal time.

The cert will come up for renewal soon, and the certificate service sent me a notification about that prompting me to re-up the cert. The client is asking me how we can transfer the certificate to his name. I'm not sure if such a thing is possible, and I couldn't find any information about doing this online.

Is it somehow possible to transfer ownership of the certificate to my former client, or should he simply buy a new certificate with an account he controls and have his current web developer(s) put that in place of the soon-to-expire certificate that I purchased?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the purchasing policies of NameCheap, and should be taken up with them.

Comment: Just have your client buy a new certificate.  If you can do so easily, help them install it, as a gesture of goodwill.

Comment: Damn, you admins really look for asinine reasons to close legitimate questions, don't you? Okay, I've removed the name-dropping from the very clearly legitimate question. Re-open it, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let them buy a new one.

You may be thinking of a process like in DNS ownership transfer. But there is no such thing for certificates.

Anyone who can answer an email for admin@example.com will get a certificate for example.com.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: Okay, I figured that'd be the case, but just wanted to confirm. Thanks.